# Table of contents properties modification

Tags: table-of-contents

I was wondering if it is possible to have a table of contents  like the picture.

The tricky part (for me) is that I still want the chapter heading pages with the name of the chapters.

To resume: I want "Chapter N...bla bla bla" page but in the table of contents it should appear 2.N.

I hope I've been clear enough in asking the question.

[image]

Comment: Note that Italian “indice“ is “table of contents” in English. The word “index” refers to what Italian calls “indice analitico”.

Answer (score 1):

The following example addresses most of the issues:

- The main numbers in the table of contents are interpreted as `part` numbers. Since these numbers only appear here, the unnumbered chapters
  are based on:

  ```
  \refstepcounter{part}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{<number>}<title>}
  \chapter*{<title>}
  ```
- The numbered chapters are set with `\chapter`, but the automatic `\addcontentsline` is disabled and enabled afterwards to set it manually to get the part number included.
- The place for chapter numbers in the table of contents need to be enlarged. This is done by key `tocnumwidth` in `\RedeclareSectionCommand`, a specialty of KOMA-Script. An alternative is package `tocloft`. With standard classes, the internal `\l@chapter` would need to be patched.
- The depth of the table of contents is restricted to chapters, controlled by counter `tocdepth`.
- The two-digits page numbers in the table of contents are implemented with a trick. A formatting command `\FormatPageNumber` is smuggled in `\thepage` and redefined for the table of contents.
- Sans-serif font for titles comes as default setting of KOMA-Script.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}% or scrbook
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\addto\captionsitalian{%
  \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Index/Indice}%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  tocnumwidth=2.5em%
]{chapter}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}% only chapters are added to the table of contents

\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}.0}

\newcommand*{\NonNumChapter}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \refstepcounter{part}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}%
  \chapter*{#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\NumChapter}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \let\SavedAddContentsLine\addcontentsline
  \renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[3]{}%
  \chapter{#1}%
  \let\addcontentsline\SavedAddContentsLine
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
    \protect\numberline{\arabic{part}.\thechapter}#1%
  }% 
}

\renewcommand*{\thepage}{%
  \protect\FormatPageNumber{\arabic{page}}%
}
\newcommand*{\FormatPageNumber}[1]{#1}

\newcommand*{\TableOfContents}{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\FormatPageNumber}[1]{%
      \ifnum##1<10 0\fi
      ##1%
    }
    \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\StartOfNumChapters}{%
  \refstepcounter{part}%
}

\begin{document}

\TableOfContents

\NonNumChapter{Introduzione}

\StartOfNumChapters

\NumChapter{Capitolo I}

\section{First section in capitolo I}
The last chapter is \ref{chap:last} on page \pageref{chap:last}.

\NumChapter{Capitolo II}

\NumChapter{Capitolo III}
\label{chap:last}

\NonNumChapter{Conclusioni}

\NonNumChapter{Note}

\NonNumChapter{Bibliografia e Fonti}

\NonNumChapter{Acknowledgements}

\NonNumChapter{Allegati}

\NonNumChapter{Currculum (Breve CV dottorando)}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

First chapter on page 3:

> [image: First chapter on page 3]

Not implemented are:

- Position of title for table of contents. It's neither left aligned nor centered, too arbitrary for my taste.
- I dislike title in uppercase, because it is less readable as normal cased text. AFAIK, the uppercase titles comes from the time of typewriters, where different fonts are quite difficult or usually impossible. But nowadays bold fonts are a piece of cake.
- Italics is not used in the table of contents. The font is already bold, the additional use of italics is too exaggerated for my taste.

Comment: Thanks Heiko Oberdiek,
this is awesome.

I'll try it soon.